# html input field not being submitted

Tags: jquery, html

In the following code, I have three parameters "fromdate", "todate", and "host".  For some reason, "host" is not being submitted.

Output in browser address bar:

https://example.com/?fromdate=2017-01-03&todate=2017-01-11

```
<form action="http://example.com">
<div style="float: left;">
Start Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="fromdate"></div>
End Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="todate">
Host: <input type="text" name="host">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker( { dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the name to something else, just to see if you're hitting a weird naming bug? i.e. "host_value" or something, just to see... Seems to work for me on Chrome...

Comment: That did it.  I changed it to host_value and it worked.  Nice call.

Comment: Crazy... Which browser is that?

Comment: Interestingly enough, Chrome.